# how get basic threads in scala to ouput to screen?

Tags: scala

I need to implement basic multi-threading in Scala. This is a simple thread program, but I receive no ouput.

I am assuming it is because the main thread finishes faster than the created threads.

How can I modify the code to make the main thread "wait" long enough to see the ouput of the other threads ?

I'm using an older version of `scala 2.7.5` because i need some linear algebra libraries it has

```
List("one", "two", "three", "four").foreach { name =>
  new Thread { 
    override def run() = { 
      println("Thread " + name + " says Hello World!") 
      } 
    }.start
}
```

Comment: [Thread has API documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) Search for "wait" and you'll find the `join` method.

Answer (score 3):

Use `Future` instead of `Thread`. For waiting you can use `Await`. And don't forget add `ExecutionContext`. For example:

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}


val futures = List("one", "two", "three", "four").map { name =>
  Future {
    println("Thread " + name + " says Hello World!")
  }
}
Await.ready(Future.sequence(futures), Duration.Inf)
```

More information about `Future` you can find here: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i get these import errors http://pastebin.com/hiFrA3qV   should i add some parameter to `scalac` during compile. Also (editted question) i'm using scala version `2.7.5`

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing this to use Threads directly, then you can just treat them like the Java API. One way to pause execution of the main Thread until each of the other Threads are finished using [join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html).

```
val strList = List("one", "two", "three", "four")

/* map over each of the strings, creating a list of Threads, one for each String */
val threadList = strList.map { name =>
  new Thread { 
    override def run() = {
      println("Thread " + name + " says Hello World!") 
    } 
  }
}
/* Start each Thread */
threadList.foreach {_.start}

/* Join the main thread to each Thread in the list */
threadList.foreach {_.join}
```

Alternatively, Scala provides high level abstractions over Threads such as [Futures](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html). With a Future, using the same list of Strings, you could create a list of Futures and await the results of the Futures.

```
val futureList = strList.map { name =>
  Future{println("Thread " + name + " says Hello World!")} 
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i get these import errors http://pastebin.com/HV0FGMJP should i add some parameter to `scalac` during compile. Also (editted question) i'm using scala version `2.7.5`

Comment: Futures lived in the actor package in 2.7. The apidoc is here. http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.7.4/. I think the usage of futures will be different in that version, but I don't have details